# How to disable the automatic preventDefault and stopPropagate in Backbone.Marionette?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I know Marionette calls `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` by default, however, this prevents a menu of mine from closing.

Is there a way to re-enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got lucky with a google query.

`Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  triggers: {
    "click .do-something": {
      event: "something:do:it",
      preventDefault: true, // this param is optional and will default to true
      stopPropagation: false
    }
  }
});`